# Creating a jQuery Plugin without passing in a Container

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have created a simple jQuery plugin but want it to be able to run without any specified container.

The way it works now is like this.

Example Plugin

```
(function($) {

 $.fn.demo = function(options) {

 }
 })(jQuery);
```

The way the plugin is called right now is like this

```
$('#container').demo();
```

The way i want to call it is like this

```
$.demo();
```

If someone can tell me how to do it would really appreaciate it.

Comment: So, what you really want is a function. `function demo (options) {...}` you can then store that function wherever you want. `$.demo = demo;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps this can help :

**html code :**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="java/jquery-ui-1/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="java/demo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        console.log("start");
        $.demo("say hello to demo");
    });
</script>
```

**demo.js**

```
;(function ($) {
    $.demo = function (options) {
        //this.$el = $(element);
        showmessage(options);
    };

    function showmessage(options) {
        console.log(options);
    };
})(jQuery);
```